# Is Korra the last Avatar?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

*The Legend of Korra* will most likely be the last Avatar series ([Legend Of Korra Co-Creators On 'Avatar](http://www.kpopstarz.com/articles/128783/20141027/avatar-the-last-airbender-sequel.htm)) so this question is purely academical.

In book 2 Unalaq kills Raava and with this, Korra's connection with the past Avatars.

Her connection with Raava is later restored, but for the rest of the series, she never regains her connection with the past Avatars.

Can we conclude from this that she is the Last Avatar, breaking the cycle?

Comment: She might be the last avatar in the same way Aang was the last airbender.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, she is merely the beginning of a new cycle.  Her connection to the past avatars was destroyed, but upon merging with Raava again, she became a full Avatar again.  There's no indication that when she dies, the Avatar cycle will end.

Essentially, she's no different from Wan, the first Avatar.  She's merged with Raava, she has the ability to bend all the elements (and energy).  The next Avatar will have access to her, just as she used to have access to past Avatars.

Answer (score -1):

the cycle isnt broken she got ravaa back later because the spirit of light regrows in the spirit of darkness thats why the spirits didnt kill each other just controlled each other

but because its a ''different'' ravaa there will still be a new avatar but for the avatar after korra korra will be the only one that he/she can reach because he/she wont be able to connect to the avatars from the old ravaa﻿

Answer (score -2):

Yes Korra is not the last avatar there will be another avatar after korra but when that avatar goes into the avatar state it wont be powerful as it was when korra went in it but the cycle will continue to get stronger. The next avatar first element with be earth bending it goes in order

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to clarify your statements? I don't understand exactly what you're saying. And do you have a source for this information?

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide some evidence.