# Are the spirits of old cycle Avatars dead?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

I know Korra is the last avatar of the old cycle and the first avatar of the new. But is it just the connection that's lost and they are still there or has something happened to the spirits of the old cycle who carry the knowledge and memories?
If Korra started a new cycle does that mean we can never see Aang's spirit again even if any new story comes up except in flashbacks? Or any of the other avatars of old cycle. I know the connection between Korra and other avatars was cut but is it just that since the visual in the show of them getting erased one by one seems like they are actually dying.

If so, does Katara know about it?

Also does that mean all the knowledge of the past is lost to next cycle Avatars?

I am a little late to the Avatar party but I recently watched both series and love the last Airbender series so much. The solace that the avatar is never really gone due to incarnation is lost if the old cycle died which is just sad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Korra the last Avatar?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76971/77395); I do believe it addresses your questions.

Comment: No, I know Korra is the last avatar of the old cycle and the first avatar of the new. But is it just the connection that's lost and they are still there or has something happened to the spirits of the old cycle who carry the knowledge and memories??

Comment: I was writing an answer but realised it is more complicated than it looks. From my understanding, the old avatars were already died, so were their spirits. The connection happened due to Raava. Aang wasn't speaking to Roku's spirit, he was communicating with Raava who also lived with Roku.

Comment: @C.Koca does that mean its Raava's next (second or maybe she was defeated before too?) birth?? And so she doesn't remember the previous avatars?

Comment: I guess so. But as I said before, the reason I didn't write an answer is that it is a little complicated. I don't know if the producers ever commented on this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the connection to the Avatars before Korra is lost. Unless some Avatar before Korra had left a physical record of their knowledge, then it is completely lost. The next Avatar, however, will have access to all of Korra's knowledge and be able to communicate with her because Korra restarted the Uh-vatar cycle, so she is the first Avatar in this new cycle.

Comment: This makes sense, but it would be an even better answer if you could point to some evidence for it.

Comment: I can only find things from the fandom, would you count that asa reliable source? I mean, I have seen other people use it...